# Determine all columns from a table and write them separated by commas in a variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-iq

```
--Dummy table
create table table1 (
column_order varchar (100)
)

insert into table1 values ('column1')
insert into table1 values ('column2')
insert into table1 values ('column3')
insert into table1 values ('column4')
insert into table1 values ('column5')
insert into table1 values ('column6')

--Start of select

declare @rowsCount INT
declare @i INT = 1
declare @column varchar(1000) = ''

set @rowsCount = (select COUNT(*) from table1)

while @i <= @rowsCount
begin
 set @column = @column + (select column_order from table1 where rowid(table1) = @i) + ', '
 set @i = @i + 1
end
select @column
```

This code has the function ROWID thats an IQ-Sybase funktion, and im not sure what other DBMS can use it. And above you have a example what i want my select to look like.

My problem is, you cant use the ROWID function with sys.column or any other systables. Has anyone an idea how to get the same select as mine without using the ROWID function.

If you are using IQ, i constructed the code so you can just type f5 and see the select statement, after that just drop the dummy table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list().  It works in both the ASA system and IQ catalogs.

```
drop table if exists table1
go

create local temporary table table1 (
column_order varchar (100)
) in system --create table in system

insert into table1 values ('column1')
insert into table1 values ('column2')
insert into table1 values ('column3')
insert into table1 values ('column4')
insert into table1 values ('column5')
insert into table1 values ('column6')

declare @columns varchar(100)

select @columns = list(column_order) from table1

select @columns
go
```

Comment: You are the man, thank you so much, i wondered if there is another function for columns, and i could find it!!! Asd for the solution of tschmit007
im not sure what dbms are you using, maybe msdn or ASE? Because even if it is tsql, that will not work in IQ while there is a big difference in the system tables and they way things work in IQ, and i didnt have the time to test it in ASE, but thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I may be not understand your need, because I can't see why you need rowdid.

Usually, in TSQL, I do as follow:

```
declare @someVar as nvarchar(max)

set @someVar = (select 
    '[' + c.name + '],' as 'data()'
from
    sys.columns c
    join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where
    t.name = 'SomeTableName'
for xml path(''))

print Left(@someVar, Len(@someVar) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need to use a cursor:

```
-- @MyTableID has to be definded somewhere or replace
DECLARE @columns varchar(32000)
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT syscolumn.column_name FROM syscolumn WHERE syscolumn.table_id = @MyTableID
OPEN my_cursor
FETCH NEXT my_cursor into @column
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- put your magic here
        -- e.g.
        -- SET @columns = @columns + column
        FETCH NEXT my_cursor_pkey into @column
    END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```

Not tested yet, but something like that should work.